# Detect A Substream

Tags: .net, excel, filestream

"The MS-XLS file format contains streams, substreams, and records." -[Understanding the Excel MS-XLS Binary Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg615597.aspx)

Given an xls file stream:

```
FileStream stream = System.IO.File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
var xs = new List<int>();
for(int i = 0; i < stream.Length;i++)
{
 xs.Add(stream.ReadByte());
}
```

How would I go about detecting substreams? Is the name deceiving in that the substreams are actually included in the stream in some sort of sequence?

Comment: @DanielMošmondor - There is a specific question here, and unfortunately I think you misunderstood what is going on. I am using a filestream to compose a byte array from a .xls file in .net. Therefore, my file stream contains an xls structured stream. It is composed of substreams among other things. Please read up before you comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XLS (and other MS Office formats from before Office 2007) is a structured storage file aka compound binary file (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_Structured_Storage). Structured storage is like a filesystem inside of a file, where files are referred to as "streams", and directories are called "storages". A structured storage file has a single root "storage", which can contain streams and other storages, and it appears that's where all the streams in an xls file reside (which is probably why their documentation skips over the concept of "storages" and refers to streams as "substreams").

Normally, you would access structured storage using the IStorage interface (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380015%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but that may not be the most convenient method in .NET.

For accessing the data in structured storage in .NET, I'd suggest using OpenMCDF - http://sourceforge.net/projects/openmcdf/ - but I haven't tried it myself so I can't make any promises regarding its quality.

"Records" are not part of the structured storage file format, and I think you will need to parse them out of streams yourself.

Depending on what you're trying to do, it may be appropriate to use a higher-level interface instead of worrying about the details of the XLS format.

Comment: I am trying to parse out the formatting from an xls file. I have the data for the cells, but cannot figure out how to get the format for them.

Answer (score 0):

"OLE compound file: A form of structured storage, as described in [MS-CFB]. A compound file allows independent storages and streams to exist within a single file." -MS

Basically, this stream is reflecting the structure used to store the file and the term "substream" should at least be defined in the MSDN library.

All files can be represented as byte arrays read from streams, and structuring the streams is very common. In .NET a filestream is used to gather this data, and can be used on any file such as a .xls, .jpg, .doc, etc.